Using Past Perfect with the prepositional phrase: "in two hours"?
How does "in" work in a sentence?


When I collected my stuff, I left



after I collected I left



When I collected my stuff in 2 hours, I left



Is it okay with the same meaning as 1 or should I use past perfect "when I had collected my stuff" because of "in 20 minutes"? Meaning I managed to finish collecting my stuff in just 2 minutes' time


No 1. is clear: She hugged you when you arrived.
"...after I arrived" could imply a delay before she hugged you. "When" is more common, unless you are making a point. She could hardly have hugged you before you arrived.
No 2. is NOT clear. Do you mean 20 minutes after you left somewhere, 20 minutes late? Either way, the statement is puzzling and not idiomatic. Why mention 20 minutes at all? The question needs to be rephrased to make your purpose clear.

@RonaldSole check now it is different

As a British English speaker, I would say 'When I had collected my stuff, I left' (I had to collect it before I could leave). Sentence 2 makes no sense, and you mention three different time periods. You could say 'When I had spent (2 hours? 20 minutes? 2 minutes?) collecting my stuff, I left'.

Please pretend you have never learned the word when.  Try asking a few questions like "How do I express such-and-such without using the word when ? "  I say this because much of the time, if not most of the time, you are misusing when.  You gloss your first sentence with the appropriate word -- after.

@KateBunting what about "when I spent 20 minutes collecting my stuff, I left" without past perfect?

To me, when I spent twenty minutes [doing something] implies 'during those twenty minutes'. You need the past perfect or, as Tim suggests, after.

@KateBunting Colin suggested this "When I collected my stuff, within/in less than two hours, I left." Doesn't it also suggest during that time and we would need past perfect or after to switch the meaning to after that time?

Can you explain why you want to use "when" in your constructions. Give us some context because otherwise we keep going in circles, users advising to use the adverb +after* and you posting a new question about the past using when. Past Continuous works best for two actions happening at the same time: "When I was collecting my staff, I received a phone message” Past Perfect works to talk about the sequence of events. See previous comments.

An expression like in two hours is normally used only meaning "two hours from now", referring to the future.
Using it in the past is unusual, and its meaning is not clear. If I heard When I collected my stuff in two hours I would probably take that to mean "at some time within two hours of some previously established point in time", but it is not a normal way of saying it.
The meaning that I think you are trying to express is best achieved
with "within", or more naturally, "in less than";  but it is a parenthetical comment and should be set off with commas:

When I collected my stuff, within/in less than two hours, I left.


@Coline Fine. Does "within" influence the meaning of a sentence? For instance "When I watched a movie she joined me" at least to me implies she joined me during the movie. What If I add "within"? "When I watched a movie, within 25 minutes, she joined me". Same meaning during the movie?

@marta: using within this way is always adding an extra limitation beyond what is already there, which is why I set "set off within commas"!. It also suggests that there is a particular reason for specifying the time - perhaps that it is unexpected, or unusually long or short. "When I watched a movie she joined me" is ambiguous as to when she joined me, though it's most likely to mean that she joined me for the whole of watching the movie. Your second sentence is more precise about when she joined me, but suggests there is some special significance to that "25 minutes".
